# VMware workstation access device behind virtual adapter in VM from other VM

Tags: windows, networking, vmware, vmware-workstation, network-adapter

I feel like this is is gonna be an odd one but i'm trying to see if the following is possible,
I've got a device at ip `169.254.11.22` behind a virtual ethernet adapter inside a VMWare (VMWare workstation).

Running ipconfig there shows:

```
Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::e0e3:f1:570d:ec5d%13
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.236.93
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : dn.mpdh.local
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::cd7c:7e49:4ec7:6e9c%15
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.245.90.106
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.245.90.251

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::6490:3b00:f912:c4b0%14
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.196.176
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

'Ethernet' and 'Wifi' are bridged connections to my host OS. 'Ethernet 2' is the virtual network adapter.

I've then got a second VM, which only has the 'Ethernet' and 'Wifi' bridged connections.

I'd like to be able to access the `169.254.11.22` device in my first VM from my second VM. Is this  possible and how should I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

First, 169.254.x.y is the internal"DHCP not found" address. You cannot connect through that.

Your host wireless connection should show up as Ethernet to a Guest machine. I see that here.

If you use Bridged networking, you can communicate readily between machines.

If you use NAT networking, you can still communicate, but I use IP addressing for this to make things simple.

Typically there is one NAT network. You can add another one (VMware Network Editor) but that is not likely to help you here.

> I've then got a second VM, which only has the 'Ethernet' and 'Wifi'
> bridged connections.

Figure out if this is true. I do not think so. Typically a VMware Workstation guest will have one IP address. Ethernet via NAT or Bridged networking. Any wireless adapter that shows up will be by USB wireless card and passthrough.  I do not believe this will facilitate communication between guests.

And to belt and suspender, you cannot use 169.254.x.y to connect to anything.